# How to get the first row before specific date for each user and the rows after in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, fetch, mariadb

I have table online_users_changes where I store whenever user go online/idle/offline.

```
CREATE TABLE online_users_changes(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, user_id INT, timestamp TIMESTAMP, status TEXT);
INSERT INTO online_users_changes(user_id, timestamp, status) VALUES 
(1, "2014-07-05 9:00", "idle"),
(1, "2014-07-05 12:00", "online"),
(1, "2014-07-05 15:00", "offline"),
(2, "2014-07-05 7:00", "offline"),
(2, "2014-07-05 13:00", "online"),
(2, "2014-07-05 14:00", "offline");
```

I want to create chart, where I will show user's status in specific period of time. So I need to fetch all changes in this period + the most recent changes before it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM online_users_changes 
WHERE timestamp >= :start and timestamp < :end
ORDER BY user_id, timestamp
```

This query returns only changes between :start and :end, but I also need the most recent change before :start for each user.

How can I get the data I want?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8147a9/2

e.g. This query

```
SELECT *
FROM online_users_changes 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN "2014-07-05 11:00" and "2014-07-05 22:00" 
ORDER BY user_id, timestamp;
```

returns

```
| USER_ID |                   TIMESTAMP |  STATUS |
|---------|-----------------------------|---------|
|       1 | July, 05 2014 12:00:00+0000 |  online |
|       1 | July, 05 2014 15:00:00+0000 | offline |
|       2 | July, 05 2014 13:00:00+0000 |  online |
|       2 | July, 05 2014 14:00:00+0000 | offline |
```

But I want to obtains something like this.

```
| USER_ID |                   TIMESTAMP |  STATUS |
|---------|-----------------------------|---------|
|       1 | July, 05 2014 09:00:00+0000 |    idle |
|       1 | July, 05 2014 12:00:00+0000 |  online |
|       1 | July, 05 2014 15:00:00+0000 | offline |
|       2 | July, 05 2014 07:00:00+0000 | offline |
|       2 | July, 05 2014 13:00:00+0000 |  online |
|       2 | July, 05 2014 14:00:00+0000 | offline |
```

Comment: Thanks, I've included it.

Comment: I suppose you actually want "to obtain the **most recent** change before the start date", i.e. the one with the highest `timestamp`?

Comment: I assumed the same; hence the max timestamp in my answer.   Hopefully this helps, unless someone has a better answer.

Comment: @RandomSeed Exactly, I want to obtain the most recent change before the start date.

Comment: You don't want to use an inclusive upper-bound (`<=`) with timestamps [like `BETWEEN` uses](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  This seems to be a [tag:gaps-and-islands] problem, although most solutions are easier on other dbs.  @Strawberry - The table definition does have an autogen-id, but that's not going to help for this query.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I've edited sql to use `WHERE timestamp >= :start and timestamp < :end`, it seems to work properly. Thanks for a tip, I didn't know about a gaps-and-islands problem. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c4fd/3 @Strawberry Primary key is on id, I haven't mention it as it doesn't seem important to me. It's updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this (very similar to bitsm post):

```
 select user_id, Max(timestamp) as timestamp, status
 FROM online_users_changes 
 WHERE timestamp < "2014-07-05 11:00"
 group by user_id, status
 union all
 SELECT user_id, timestamp, status
 FROM online_users_changes 
 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN "2014-07-05 11:00" and "2014-07-05 22:00" 
 ORDER BY user_id, timestamp;
```

Here's the sqlfiddle for you.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8147a9/8

**UPDATE**
I tried the following update, based on new data given.  It may need some cleanup though, as I personally think the query looks nasty, despite it's success in working.

```
 SELECT user_id, max(timestamp) as timestamp, status 
 from (SELECT user_id, timestamp, status 
  FROM online_users_changes
  WHERE timestamp < "2014-07-05 11:00"
  GROUP BY user_id, status
 ) a
 group by user_id
 union all
 (SELECT user_id, timestamp, status
 FROM online_users_changes 
 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN "2014-07-05 11:00" and "2014-07-05 22:00" )
 ORDER BY user_id, timestamp;
```

SQL Fiddle here.   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bd390/44

IF anyone has any other suggestions, feel free to provide another suggestion.

Comment: @RandomSeed No, you're right. I want to return just the first row before, not all of them.

Comment: @Tiny Haitian Not really, look at RandomSeed's example, it returns 2 rows before the start date for user 1.

Comment: but isn't the timestamp of 9:01 have idle next to it, not online?  sounds like we need a bit more tweaking.

Comment: @velblúd - Warning - the second query will return unstable results, and may silently "fail", by returning incorrect data.  When this query runs, the value of `timestamp` the subquery contains is **UNDEFINED** - there is _no guaranteed way to control the value returned_.  You get whatever the optimizer decides to give you, which _might_ be the results you expect, but can very well be something else.  Do **NOT** use it.  All other RDBMSs would consider it a syntax error.

Comment: Then @Clockwork-Muse, what's your suggestion?  I'd like to see it myself.  I'm open to figuring stuff like this out.

Comment: I too would like to know how to do this properly. I implemented the second query suggested in this answer and it seemed to work as expected, though I honestly do not even understand why. Then I read the comment by Clockwork-Muse who warns about using it. But does it only apply to the second one? I tried the first and it seems to give the same result.

Comment: @Clox I used the second query in my long abandoned personal project and it worked just fine. I **think** the problem with it is that if there is no row satisfying the first condition (`WHERE timestamp < "2014-07-05 11:00"`) than it returns quietly false result. These 2 years old sqlfiddles links don't work for me, so I can't test it. Anyway, if you find another/better solution, let me know, I am still curious about some nicer solution.

Comment: Using any sort of grouping expression and then assuming that that will actually select that row is bogus: SELECT MAX(id), status will return the maximum id and some random value for status, not the status value from the row that MAX(id) as in. See RandomSeed's answer for the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

"the most recent event before a given date" = "the first event that took place before a given date, when sorting events in reverse chronological order" =

```
SELECT * FROM online_users_changes
WHERE timestamp < "your date and time here"
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Then `UNION` this row with the main query.

Beware, using `ORDER BY` clauses together with `UNION` is somewhat tricky, you'll need parenthesis at the right places (the [manual pages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html) have it all).

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you provide example how to union with my query? It's not clear to me.

Comment: This page is full of examples, isn't it?

Comment: After you mentioned the parenthesis, it's clean :) First right answer, thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, but I want to get the the most recent event for EACH USER. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_id, timestamp, status
FROM online_users_changes 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN "2014-07-05 11:00" and "2014-07-05 22:00" 
Union
Select user_id, timestamp, status
From online_users_changes as temp
Where date(timestamp)="2014-07-05" and timestamp<"2014-07-05 11:00"
ORDER BY user_id, timestamp;
```

Comment: No it doesn't really work as specified. This will return all status changes on the same day prior to the main time span.

Comment: It won't work if the first row before would be from another day. e.g. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03ff0

Comment: Calling `DATE(timestamp)` will cause indices to be ignored for that comparison, which might be a factor on large dbs.